# How to update array of arrays or array of objects in draft of immer without crashing page

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga, immer.js

I have an array of arrays which is kept on changing on different operations, and I need to update the same in the draft of immer as shown below (Using React with Redux and Immer).

```
    return produce(state, draft => {
        switch (action) {
           case SCENERIO1:
                 .
                 .
   Some Logic To generate updated Array
                 .
                 .
             draft.someArrayofArrays = modifiedArrayOfArrays; 
             break;
           }
        }
    }
```

My Scenario is, I have 100 items in **someArrayofArrays** of draft. I have new updated array **modifiedArrayOfArrays** which I want to reassign to `draft.someArrayofArrays`. So, this reassigning of updated array slows down/crashes if the array size is around 100 or more.

Am I doing anything wrong, or how to update the draft if my whole array is changing on each operation?

Comment: Can you share all the relevant code you are working with as part of the [mcve]? You mention removing items from an array. What is the issue? How are you removing elements from the array?

Comment: My question is specific to immer; when I am assigning new data to draft, it starts crashing if my array of arrays is just of length 100. So, what's the correct way to update data to the immer draft?

Comment: I don't think immer.js cares much one way or the other *what* you are saving. I suspect your issue is somewhere in the `... Some Logic To generate updated Array ...` bit with *how* you are computing the value. Either way though, we can't help diagnose or debug code we can't see. Please edit your post to include a complete [mcve].

Comment: This is an issue with immer in handling data with deep objects, some part of the issue is resolved by upgrading version 3. x of immer to 9. x

Answer (score 0):

= =,hello,bro
Maybe it just like below

```
    switch(action){
       case 1:func1();//break;
       case 2:func2();//break;
    
    }
```

so, it is solw down after you exceeds.50 ,,hhhhh
it is my guess..

Comment: My Question is around this area of code draft.someArrayofArrays = modifiedArrayOfArrays;

Comment: oh , you fix you question ??  
maybe be , you should  use binary tree data struct，this  is O(logN),,,array delete is O(n)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had some success with Immer and multidimensional arrays (in Typescript). I needed to do complicated data transformations and I needed a clone of the state value that I could work with.

I used similar code to produce a copy of the state's MyProductType[][]

```
 state.products = MyProductType[][]

let clonedState = state.products.map((proxyArray: MyProductType[]) => {
              let innerArray = Array.from(proxyArray);
              innerArray = innerArray.map((product) => {
                let clonedProduct = {...product}
                let clonedTags = product.tags.map((tag: string) => tag + '');
                clonedProduct.tags = clonedTags;
                return clonedProduct;
              });
              return innerArray
            });
```